# Numpy dot product with 3d array

Tags: numpy

I've got two arrays:

- `data` of shape `(2466, 2498, 9)`, where the dimensions are `(asset, date, returns)`.
- `correlation_matrix` of shape `(2466, 2466)` (with 0's on the diagonal)

I want to get the dot product that equates to the expected returns, which is the `returns` of each `asset` multiplied by the `correlation_matrix`. It should give a shape the same as `data`.

I've tried:

```
data.transpose([1, 2, 0]) @ correlation_matrix
```

but this just hangs my PC (been going 10 minutes and counting).

I also tried:

```
np.einsum('ijk,lm->ijk', data, correlation_matrix)
```

but I'm less familiar with `einsum`, and this also hangs.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Think you can just do `data*correlation_matrix.sum()`, assuming your `einsum` works.

Comment: If things are hanging or taking too long, step back and test something smaller.  Make sure the code is doing what you want with small arrays before stressing memory with something large.

Comment: Your `einsum` just sums all values of `correlation_matrix` and multiplies `data` by the resulting scalar.  That probably not what  you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to do this product:

```
# as you already suggested:
data.transpose([1, 2, 0]) @ correlation_matrix

# using einsum
np.einsum('ijk,il', data, correlation_matrix)

# using tensordot to explicitly specify the axes to sum over
np.tensordot(data, correlation_matrix, axes=(0,0))
```

All of them should give the same result. The timing for some small matrices was more or less the same for me. So your problem is the large amount of data, not an inefficient implementation.

```
A=np.arange(100*120*9).reshape((100, 120, 9))
B=np.arange(100**2).reshape((100,100))

timeit('A.transpose([1,2,0])@B', globals=globals(), number=100)
# 0.747475513999234
timeit("np.einsum('ijk,il', A, B)", globals=globals(), number=100)
# 0.4993825999990804
timeit('np.tensordot(A, B, axes=(0,0))', globals=globals(), number=100)
# 0.5872082839996438
```

Answer (score 2):

With your `.transpose((1, 2, 0))` data, the correct form is:

```
"ijs,sk"  # -> ijk
```

Since for a tensor `A` and `B`, we can write:

```
C_{ijk} = Σ_s A_{ijs} * B_{sk}
```

If you want to avoid transposing your data beforehand, you can just permute the indices:

```
"sij,sk"  # -> ijk
```

To verify:

```
p, q, r = 2466, 2498, 9

a = np.random.randint(255, size=(p, q, r))
b = np.random.randint(255, size=(p, p))

c1 = a.transpose((1, 2, 0)) @ b
c2 = np.einsum("sij,sk", a, b)

>>> np.all(c1 == c2)
True
```

The amount of *multiplications* needed to compute this for `(p, q, r)` shaped `data` is `p * np.prod(c.shape) == p * (q * r * p) == p**2 * q * r`. In your case, that is `136_716_549_192` multiplications. You also need approximately the same number of additions, so that gives us somewhere close to 270 billion operations. If you want more speed, you could consider using a GPU for your computations via [cupy](https://cupy.chainer.org/).

```
def with_np():
    p, q, r = 2466, 2498, 9
    a = np.random.randint(255, size=(p, q, r))
    b = np.random.randint(255, size=(p, p))
    c1 = a.transpose((1, 2, 0)) @ b
    c2 = np.einsum("sij,sk", a, b)

def with_cp():
    p, q, r = 2466, 2498, 9
    a = cp.random.randint(255, size=(p, q, r))
    b = cp.random.randint(255, size=(p, p))
    c1 = a.transpose((1, 2, 0)) @ b
    c2 = cp.einsum("sij,sk", a, b)

>>> timeit(with_np, number=1)
513.066

>>> timeit(with_cp, number=1)
0.197
```

That's a speedup of 2600, *including* memory allocation, initialization, and CPU/GPU copy times! (A more realistic benchmark would give an even larger speedup.)

Comment: Wow, that's an incredible speedup! What kind of GPU do you have? That might be worth investment ;)

Comment: @cjm2671 It's a bit "outdated" -- NVIDIA GTX 1060 6GB ($300 when purchased, 5 years ago). You can probably get a newer graphics card model for cheaper than this card is  being sold for nowadays, though. If you want CUDA computations, I recommend sticking with NVIDIA.

Comment: Well, looks like they're around $30 now on ebay, seems like a worthy investment ! Thank you! :)